# Creating div tag dynamically based on rows count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a database table which has rows. Based on the table rows, I want to create div tags dynamically. My requirement is like I have to create divs based on the database rows count.

- If 5 rows are there in the db, then 1 div will be created.
- If 20 rows are there in the db, then 2 divs will be created.
- If 25 rows are there in the db, then 3 divs will be created.
- If 56 rows are there in the db, then 6 divs will be created.

The 1st div should be beside the 2nd div.

Below is the javascript function I'm using:

```
function LoadData(data)
{   
    var rows_count = 22; -- will be fetched from DB side
    var rowNum = Math.ceil(parseFloat(rows_count));

    var resultHtml = '';

    resultHtml += "<table style = \'width:100%;\' border=\'0\' colspan=\'2\' id=\'tbl_user\'>";    
    for (var i = 0; i <=rowNum-1 ; i++) {
        resultHtml += '<tr>';
        resultHtml += '<td border = 1><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>';        
        resultHtml += '</tr>';         
        }
    }  
    resultHtml += '</table>';
}
```

I have written out the logic, but 22 rows are creating only one div tag.
I want to show 10 records in 1 div and another 10 records in the 2nd div and so on.

Comment: 25 and 56 for both you want 3 div....? And you want `<div></div>` or `<tr><td></td></tr>`

Comment: Sorry typo mistake... for 56 rows it will be 6 div

Comment: do you want a pagination on table?

Answer (score 1):

Your Solution

```js
$('#rows').change(function(e) {
    var rows_count = parseInt($(this).val()); 
 var div_count = Math.ceil(rows_count/10);
 resultHtml = '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr>';
 j=0;l=0;
 for (var i = 1; i<=div_count ; i++){k=0;
  if(l==4){ resultHtml += '</tr><tr>';l=0;}
  resultHtml += '<td align="center">';
  while((j<rows_count)&&(k<10)){ resultHtml += '<input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."><br>';j++;k++;}
  resultHtml += '</td>';
  l++;
 }
 resultHtml += '</tr></table>';
 $('#inputs').html(resultHtml);  
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <style>.active {
      background: red;
      color:#FFF;
    }</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="inputs"></div>
    <input type="text" id="rows" placeholder="No. of Rows" />
```

Comment: Thanks lot for your answer.   It really worked.
Only if there are 100 records then 10 divs are created horizontally.
I want only 4 div on 1line
then anothe 4 div on next line an so on... Can you please provide me solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Script Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot GYaN for your  coopration. Your solution really worked for me.
One more things:-
Currently your code is producing 1 tr and 1 td for 1 div and by using line break <br/> , we are showing details on 1 td.
Is it possible to have 10 tr and 10 td for 1 div. So that i would be nice for formatting.
Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accept... So anyone have same issue can find solution easily.. If this worked for you... thanks

Comment: Yes i am a coder. Dotnet developer. But since 4 years i never worked on javascript and jQuery. Thatswhy i asked you.
If you have a time, then please give the code.